# Error on reindexing catalog_category_product

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.7

on my magento 2.3.7-p4 i've been having an sql error on trying to index the catalog_category_product where it tries to insert the data into an non existing table and instead of the query throws an error saying that table doesn't exist it keeps trying to insert the data until it finds the table.
The table that is trying to insert the data is catalog_category_product_index_store1_tmp. But on my database there is no table created with that name.
I try to create the table but then the table temp_catalog_category_tree_index_71885f6d also didn't exist on the database.

This is the query that is running when i run the bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_category_product

```
INSERT INTO `catalog_category_product_index_store1_tmp` (`category_id`, `product_id`, `position`, `is_parent`, `store_id`, `visibility`) SELECT `cc`.`entity_id` AS `category_id`, `ccp`.`product_id`, IFNULL(ccp2.position, ccp.position + 10000) AS `position`, 0 AS `is_parent`, 1 AS `store_id`, IFNULL(cpvs.value, cpvd.value) AS `visibility` FROM `catalog_category_entity` AS `cc`
 INNER JOIN `temp_catalog_category_tree_index_71885f6d` AS `cc2` ON cc2.parent_id = cc.entity_id AND cc.entity_id NOT IN (1)
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product` AS `ccp` ON ccp.category_id = cc2.child_id
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_product` AS `ccp2` ON ccp2.category_id = cc2.parent_id AND ccp.product_id = ccp2.product_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `cpe` ON ccp.product_id = cpe.entity_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_website` AS `cpw` ON cpw.product_id = ccp.product_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `cpsd` ON cpsd.entity_id = cpe.entity_id AND cpsd.store_id = 0 AND cpsd.attribute_id = 97
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `cpss` ON cpss.entity_id = cpe.entity_id AND cpss.attribute_id = cpsd.attribute_id AND cpss.store_id = 1
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `cpvd` ON cpvd.entity_id = cpe. entity_id AND cpvd.store_id = 0 AND cpvd.attribute_id = 99
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `cpvs` ON cpvs.entity_id = cpe.entity_id AND cpvs.attribute_id = cpvd.attribute_id AND cpvs.store_id = 1
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `ccad` ON ccad.entity_id = cc.entity_id AND ccad.store_id = 0 AND ccad.attribute_id = 54
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `ccas` ON ccas.entity_id = cc.entity_id AND ccas.attribute_id = ccad.attribute_id AND ccas.store_id = 1
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_relation` AS `relation` ON cpe.entity_id = relation.parent_id
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `relation_product_entity` ON relation.child_id = relation_product_entity.entity_id
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `child_cpsd` ON child_cpsd.entity_id = relation_product_entity.entity_id AND child_cpsd.store_id = 0 AND child_cpsd.attribute_id = 97
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `child_cpss` ON child_cpss.entity_id = relation_product_entity.entity_id AND child_cpss.attribute_id = child_cpsd.attribute_id AND child_cpss.store_id = 1 WHERE (cpw.website_id = '1') AND (IFNULL(cpss.value, cpsd.value) = 1) AND (IFNULL(cpvs.value, cpvd.value) IN (2, 3, 4)) AND (IFNULL(ccas.value, ccad.value) = 1) AND (relation.child_id IS NULL OR IFNULL(child_cpss.value, child_cpsd.value) = 1) AND (ccp.product_id IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '432', '433', '434', '435', '436', '437', '438', '439', '440', '441', '442', '443', '444', '445', '446', '447', '448', '456', '457', '458', '459', '460', '461', '462', '463', '464', '465', '466', '467', '468', '469', '470', '471', '472', '473', '474', '475', '476', '477', '478', '479', '480', '481', '482', '483', '484', '485', '486', '487', '488', '489', '490', '491', '492', '493', '494', '495', '496', '497', '498', '499', '500', '501', '502', '503', '504', '505', '506', '507', '508', '509', '510', '511', '512', '513', '514', '515', '516', '517', '518', '519', '520', '521', '522', '523', '524', '525', '526', '527', '528', '529', '530', '531', '532', '533', '534', '535', '536', '537', '538', '539', '540', '541', '542', '543', '568', '569', '570', '571', '572', '573', '574', '575', '576', '577', '578', '579', '580', '581', '582', '583', '584', '585', '586', '587', '588', '589', '590', '591', '592', '593', '594', '595', '596', '597', '598', '599', '600', '601', '602', '603', '604', '605', '606', '607', '608', '609', '610', '611', '612', '613', '614', '615', '616', '617', '618', '619', '620', '621', '622', '623', '624', '625', '626', '627', '628', '629', '630', '631', '632', '633', '634', '635', '636', '637', '638', '639', '640', '641', '642', '643', '644', '645', '646', '647', '648', '649', '650', '651', '652', '653', '654', '655', '656', '657', '658', '659', '660', '661', '662', '663', '664', '665', '666', '667', '668', '669', '670', '671', '672', '673', '674', '675', '676', '677', '678', '679', '680', '681', '682', '683', '684', '685', '686', '687', '688', '689', '690', '691', '692', '693', '694', '695', '696', '697', '698', '699', '700', '701', '702', '703', '704', '705', '706', '707', '708', '709', '710', '711', '712', '713', '714', '715', '716', '717', '718', '719', '720', '721', '722', '723', '724', '725', '726', '727', '728', '729', '730', '731', '732', '733', '734', '735', '736', '737', '738', '739', '740', '741', '742', '743', '744', '745', '746', '747', '748', '749', '750', '751', '752', '753', '754', '755', '756', '757', '758', '759', '760', '761', '762', '763', '764', '765', '766', '767', '768', '769', '770', '771', '772', '773', '774', '775', '776', '777', '778', '779', '780', '781', '782', '783', '784', '785', '786', '787', '788', '789', '790', '791', '792', '793', '794', '795', '796', '797', '798', '799', '800', '801', '802', '803', '804', '805', '806', '807', '808', '809', '810', '811', '812', '813', '814', '815', '816', '817', '818', '819', '820', '821', '822', '823', '824', '825', '826', '827', '828', '829', '830', '831', '832', '833', '834', '835', '836', '837', '838', '839', '840', '841', '842', '843', '844', '845', '846', '847', '848', '849', '850', '851', '852', '853', '854', '855', '856', '857', '858', '859', '860', '861', '862', '863', '864', '865', '866', '867', '868', '869', '870', '871', '872', '873', '874', '875', '876', '877', '878', '879', '880', '881', '882', '883', '884', '885', '886', '887', '888', '889', '890', '891', '892', '893', '894', '895', '896', '897', '898', '899', '900', '901', '902', '903', '904', '905', '906', '907', '908', '909', '910', '911', '912', '913', '914', '915', '916', '917', '918', '919', '920', '921', '922', '923', '924', '925', '926', '927', '928', '929', '930', '931', '932', '933', '934', '935', '936', '937', '938', '939', '940', '941', '942', '943', '944', '945', '946', '947', '948', '949', '950', '951', '952', '953', '954', '955', '956', '957', '958', '959', '960', '961', '962', '963', '964', '965', '983', '984', '985', '986', '987', '988', '989', '990', '991', '992', '993', '994', '995', '996', '997', '998', '999', '1000', '1001', '1002', '1003', '1004', '1005', '1006', '1007', '1008', '1009', '1010', '1011', '1012', '1013', '1014', '1015', '1016', '1017', '1018', '1019', '1020', '1021', '1022', '1023', '1024', '1025', '1026', '1027', '1028', '1029', '1030', '1031', '1032', '1033', '1034', '1035', '1036', '1037', '1038', '1039', '1040', '1041', '1042', '1043', '1044', '1045', '1046', '1047', '1048', '1049', '1050', '1051', '1052', '1053', '1054', '1055', '1056', '1057', '1058', '1059', '1060', '1061', '1062', '1063', '1064', '1065', '1066', '1067', '1068', '1069', '1070', '1071', '1072', '1073', '1074', '1075', '1076', '1077', '1078', '1079', '1080', '1081', '1082', '1083', '1084', '1085', '1086', '1087', '1088', '1089', '1090', '1091', '1092', '1093', '1094', '1095', '1096', '1097', '1098', '1099', '1100', '1101', '1102', '1103', '1104', '1105', '1106', '1107', '1108', '1109', '1110', '1111', '1112', '1113', '1114', '1115', '1116', '1117', '1118', '1119', '1120', '1121', '1122', '1123', '1124', '1125', '1126', '1127', '1128', '1135', '1136', '1137', '1138', '1139', '1140', '1141', '1142', '1143', '1144', '1145', '1146', '1147', '1148', '1149', '1150', '1151', '1152', '1153', '1154', '1155', '1156', '1157', '1158', '1159', '1160', '1161', '1162', '1163', '1164', '1165', '1166', '1167', '1168', '1169', '1170', '1171', '1172', '1173', '1174', '1175', '1176', '1177', '1178', '1179', '1180', '1181', '1182', '1183', '1184', '1185', '1186', '1187', '1188', '1189', '1190', '1191', '1192', '1193', '1194', '1195', '1196', '1197', '1198', '1199', '1200', '1201', '1202', '1203', '1204', '1205', '1206', '1207', '1208', '1209', '1210', '1211', '1212', '1213', '1214', '1215', '1216', '1217', '1218', '1219', '1220', '1221', '1222', '1223', '1224', '1225', '1226', '1227', '1228', '1229', '1230', '1231', '1232', '1233', '1234', '1235', '1236', '1237', '1238', '1239', '1240', '1241', '1242', '1243', '1244', '1245', '1246', '1247', '1248', '1249', '1250', '1251', '1252', '1253', '1254', '1255', '1256', '1257', '1258', '1259', '1260', '1261', '1262', '1263', '1264', '1265', '1266', '1267', '1268', '1269', '1270', '1271', '1272', '1273', '1274', '1275', '1276', '1277', '1278', '1279', '1280', '1281', '1282', '1283', '1284', '1285', '1286', '1287', '1288', '1289', '1290', '1291', '1292', '1293', '1294', '1295', '1296', '1297', '1298', '1299', '1300', '1301', '1302', '1303', '1304', '1305', '1306', '1307', '1308', '1309', '1310', '1311', '1312', '1313', '1314', '1315', '1316', '1317', '1318', '1319', '1320', '1321', '1322', '1323', '1324', '1325', '1326', '1327', '1328', '1329', '1330', '1331', '1332', '1333', '1334', '1335', '1336', '1337', '1338', '1339', '1340', '1341', '1342', '1343', '1344', '1345', '1346', '1347', '1348', '1349', '1350', '1351', '1352', '1353', '1354', '1355', '1356', '1357', '1358', '1359', '1360', '1361', '1362', '1363', '1364', '1365', '1366', '1367', '1368', '1369', '1370', '1371', '1372', '1373', '1374', '1375', '1376', '1377', '1378', '1379', '1380', '1381', '1382', '1383', '1384', '1385', '1386', '1387', '1388', '1389', '1390', '1391', '1392', '1393', '1394', '1395', '1396', '1397', '1398', '1399', '1400', '1401', '1402', '1403', '1404', '1405', '1406', '1407', '1408', '1409', '1410', '1411', '1412', '1413', '1414', '1415', '1416')) GROUP BY `cc`.`entity_id`,
    `ccp`.`product_id`,
    `visibility` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `category_id` = VALUES(`category_id`), `product_id` = VALUES(`product_id`), `position` = VALUES(`position`), `is_parent` = VALUES(`is_parent`), `store_id` = VALUES(`store_id`), `visibility` = VALUES(`visibility`)
```

I tried to reset and then reindex but nothing works.

Comment: Have you recently perfom any action related to default store?

Comment: Hi, no there were no changes made on the default store or on any of the other stores.